# Network Internet Egress Price

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, price

I never got the right pricing policy from Google. It's a little confusing for me. I'm currently testing google compute engine to try to understand how it all works.

In a simple example when using Cloud Laucher Wordpress there is a sustainable forecast of $4,49, Using a machine Instance of the VM: 1 shared vCPU + 0.6 GB of memory (f1-micro) and standard 10G disk.

In less than 10 days of testing where I am the only user, where the instance became connected throughout the period and my use was very little. I began tracking billing details.

Look at the numbers:
Generic Micro instance with burstable CPU, no scratch disk  4.627 Minutes   $0,62
Storage PD Capacity     1,92 GB-month   $0,08

And my big surprise
Network Internet Egress from Americas to Americas   12,82 GB    $1,54
I am aware that this value is very small, this is very clear

But imagine an example 100 people making use in the same period
Network Internet Egress from Americas to Americas   Would jump $ 154,00

Is my reasoning correct?
Is there a way to lower this value?
Another doubt.
Which has the lowest cost Google compute engine or Google app engine?

Comment: Potentially of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078608/understanding-cost-estimate-for-google-cloud-platform-microservices-architecture/42103549#42103549

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't buy web server server in cloud platform unless you know the pricing strategy inside out.

Yes, GCS and other cloud platform charge a hefty sum for [Egress/outgoing traffics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network) if you are not careful, e.g. if you get DDoS on your website, you will be doomed with a huge bills.  As shown in the table, GCS is charging $0,12/GB egress

```
# Europe using "," as decimal separator 
12,82GB  x $0,12/GB = $1,5384  ~ $1,54
```

If you expect more traffics, then you should look into [Google cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing) service offer, which charge a lower egress price. However, you need to be careful when using those CDN, they will charge ingress traffics (so only allow traffics between your storage repo with the CDN).

It is a good idea to setup alarm/event alert services to warn you about abnormal traffics.

Since you are in the cloud, you should  [compare prices of CDN services](http://www.cdncalc.com/)

---

(Update)

[Google App Engine(GAE)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) is just a Platform as a Services, which Google will give you daily free resources, i.e. 1GB egress per day. $0,12/GB price still apply if you use above the limit. In addition, you are limited to the offering given, there is not web services GAE at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much mootmoot. Your answer helps me a lot to better understand this. I come from a traditional hosting model where the concept of cloud is a great novelty. I figured paying only for what I use would make things cheaper. Doing the maths can all become very expensive compared to the previous service. Still a doubt. If we compare Google compute engine with Google app engine, how would these charges?

Comment: @NiltonFelicio : GAE is PaaS that limited to the services offered.